# Qt-VTK interaction style signal to widget

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, signals-slots

I am trying to connect customized interaction style signal to main widget slot.

Header file

```
class interactorCamera : public QObject, public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static interactorCamera* New();
    interactorCamera();
    virtual void OnLeftButtonDown();

signals:
    void signalOut();

};

class mainWidget : public QVTKOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit sceneWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~sceneWidget();

public slots:
    void getSignal();

};
```

Source file

```
vtkStandardNewMacro(interactorCamera);

interactorCamera::interactorCamera(){
}

void interactorCamera::OnLeftButtonDown(){
    vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnLeftButtonDown();
    qInfo() << "Camera Interactor Left Down";
    emit trialsignal();
}


sceneWidget::sceneWidget(QWidget *parent)  QVTKOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    // Camera, renderer, source initialization and so on...
    // ...

    vInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    vInteractor->SetRenderWindow(GetRenderWindow());
    vtkSmartPointer<interactorCamera> interCamera = vtkSmartPointer<interactorCamera>::New();
    vInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(interCamera);

    connect(&interCamera, SIGNAL(trialsignal()), this, SLOT(getInteraction()));
    vInteractor->Initialize();
    vInteractor->Start();
}
```

It seems I could not connect correct types and I don't know how to do it so.
Error I got

```
error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'vtkSmartPointer<interactorCamera> *' to 'const QObject *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I tried to reinterpret_cast too but could not succeeded.

```
connect(reinterpret_cast<QObject*>(interCamera), SIGNAL(trialsignal()), this, SLOT(getInteraction()));
```

This time error is

```
error: C2440: 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'vtkSmartPointer<interactorCamera>' to 'QObject *'
Conversion requires a constructor or user-defined-conversion operator, which can't be used by const_cast or reinterpret_cast
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: it worked, thank you very much

connect(static_cast<QObject*>(interCamera.Get()), SIGNAL(trialsignal()), this, SLOT(getInteraction()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. `reintepret_cast` is not going to work because the base addresses of these two unrelated base classed are not the same.

Only proper casts will work properly.

Then you need to use `innerCamera.Get()` to get a pointer that you can really cast to a `QObject*`, as you can't do this with the original smart pointer.